# mean cross-sectional area of a sphere with radius 1

Tags: calculus, geometry, circles, means, spheres

How would you go about finding the mean cross-sectional area of a sphere that has a radius equal to $1$?

I have calculated the mean length of a chord in a circle (with radius $1$) to be $\frac{4}{\pi}$, so would I be able to use this answer to help me find the solution to this new problem?

Would I have to take into account that areas can be at varying angles, or could I assume it is the same as the mean of a set of all the areas that are parallel to each other?

Comment: The result depends on how you take the mean. In the case of a circle, your result $4/\pi$ holds if you choose uniformly at random the angle the chord subtends. But if you choose instead uniformly at random the distance of the chord from the centre, then the result is $\pi/2$.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Yes that is very true. So I am going to have to consider the angle that the cross-section sits at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you calculated the average chord in the 2D case by uniformly varying the subtended angle, I think it makes most sense to let the diameter of the cross section be defined by the chords on a [great circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_circle) of the sphere, with the subtended angle of the chord varying uniformly from $0$ to $2\pi$

For a subtended angle $\theta$, the chord length / diameter is $d(\theta)=\sqrt{(1-\cos\theta)^2+(\sin\theta)^2}=\sqrt{2-2\cos\theta}$

The area of a circle of diameter $d$ is $A(d)=\dfrac{\pi d^2}{4}$

Thus the area as a function of $\theta$ is $A(\theta)=\frac{\pi}{4}(2-2\cos\theta)$

Finding the average value $\mu$ of this over all angles
\begin{align}
\mu&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}A(\theta)d\theta\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\pi}{4}(2-2\cos\theta)d\theta\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{\pi}{4}\left[2\theta-2\sin\theta\right]_0^{2\pi}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}
\end{align}
So with this setup, the mean cross sectional area of the unit sphere is $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$

In response to your final question about accounting for areas at different angles, notice that this result is equal regardless of which great circle we vary the chord / diameter around. Therefore, by symmetry, you do not need to consider other orientations that the cross section could vary about.

Comment: Thankyou for this answer. When I attempted calculating this myself, I found the average of the area of 1 orientation (which as you said is allowed) with respect to the distance from the centre of the area to the centre of the sphere, and letting this value range from 0 to 1. In doing so, I achieved an answer of 2pi/3 which doesn't align with your answer, even after retrying multiple times. What have I done wrong here?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your answer, it just varies the cross section using a different method (in a sense, different methods weight the cross sections differently). You chose to uniformly vary the distance from the section to the centre, which would be like varying the distance from the chord to the centre in the 2D case (giving an average chord length of $\pi/2$). Both are perfectly valid interpretations of the average cross section / average chord length, which is why it is important to define what you mean by "average."

Comment: My comment on orientation being irrelevant is true if you use the same method of varying your cross sections but from a different starting point. By letting the distance from the centre of the sphere to the cross section vary, you have chosen a different method of varying, not just a different orientation.